# HDFS some datanodes of cluster are suddenly disconnected while reducers are running

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 8 slave computers and 1 master computer for running Hadoop (ver 0.21)

some datanodes of cluster are suddenly disconnected while I was running MapReduce code on 10GB data
After all mappers finished and around 80% of reducers was processed, randomly one or more datanode disconned from network. 
and then the other datanodes start to disappear from network even if I killed the MapReduce job when I found some datanode was disconnected.

I've tried to change dfs.datanode.max.xcievers to 4096, turned off fire-walls of all computing node, disabled selinux and increased the number of file open limit to 20000
but they didn't work at all...

anyone have a idea to solve this problem?

followings are error log from mapreduce

```
12/06/01 12:31:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_201206011227_0001_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ***.***.***.148:20010
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:427)
```

---

and followings are logs from datanode

```
2012-06-01 13:01:01,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_-5549263231281364844_3453 src: /*.*.*.147:56205 dest: /*.*.*.142:20010
2012-06-01 13:01:01,136 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(*.*.*.142:20010, storageID=DS-1534489105-*.*.*.142-20010-1337757934836, infoPort=20075, ipcPort=20020) Starting thread to transfer block blk_-3849519151985279385_5906 to *.*.*.147:20010
2012-06-01 13:01:19,135 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(*.*.*.142:20010, storageID=DS-1534489105-*.*.*.142-20010-1337757934836, infoPort=20075, ipcPort=20020):Failed to transfer blk_-5797481564121417802_3453 to *.*.*.146:20010 got java.net.ConnectException: > Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataTransfer.run(DataNode.java:1257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2012-06-01 13:06:20,342 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Verification succeeded for blk_6674438989226364081_3453
2012-06-01 13:09:01,781 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(*.*.*.142:20010, storageID=DS-1534489105-*.*.*.142-20010-1337757934836, infoPort=20075, ipcPort=20020):Failed to transfer blk_-3849519151985279385_5906 to *.*.*.147:20010 got java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 480000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for write. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/*.*.*.142:60057 remote=/*.*.*.147:20010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.waitForIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.waitForWritable(SocketOutputStream.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.transferToFully(SocketOutputStream.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendChunks(BlockSender.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendBlock(BlockSender.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataTransfer.run(DataNode.java:1284)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/data/name</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
              <value>/home/hadoop/data/hdfs1,/home/hadoop/data/hdfs2,/home/hadoop/data/hdfs3,/home/hadoop/data/hdfs4,/home/hadoop/data/hdfs5</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>3</value>
     </property>

     <property>
               <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
              <value>4096</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.http.address</name>
            <value>0.0.0.0:20070</value>
            <description>50070
      The address and the base port where the dfs namenode web ui will listen on.
      If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
            </description>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
            <value>0.0.0.0:20075</value>
            <description>50075
      The datanode http server address and port.
      If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
            </description>
     </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:20090</value>
      <description>50090
      The secondary namenode http server address and port.
      If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:20010</value>
      <description>50010
      The address where the datanode server will listen to.
      If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
      </description>

 <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:20020</value>
      <description>50020
      The datanode ipc server address and port.
      If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:20475</value>
    </property>

        <property>
         <name>dfs.https.address</name>
          <value>0.0.0.0:20470</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

---

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
            <value>masternode:29001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.system.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/mapreduce/system</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/mapreduce/local</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
            <value>32</value>
            <description> default number of map tasks per job.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
            <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
            <value>8</value>
            <description> default number of reduce tasks per job.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.map.child.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx2048M</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>io.sort.mb</name>
            <value>500</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
            <value>1800000</value> <!-- 30 minutes -->
    </property>


    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
            <value>0.0.0.0:20030</value>
            <description> 50030
            The job tracker http server address and port the server will listen on.
            If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port.
            </description>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>mapred.task.tracker.http.address</name>
                <value>0.0.0.0:20060</value>
                <description> 50060

         </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: 0.21 is not stable, so this is not really suprising me. Try to switch to 20.2xx. Edit: the releases have been renamed to 1.0.x

Comment: Thanks for the comment. however My co-worker using 1.0.3a version Hadoop in the same cluster encountered the same problem.

Comment: If your co-working is using 1.0.3 in the same cluster, are you mixing and matching hadoop versions? Can you check that all the services running and your job code are using the same version of hadoop

Comment: I see you also have some custom port configurations in your `hdfs-site.xml` - have these been correctly replicated across your cluster?

Comment: We're using the cluster exclusively. I checked his hdfs and mapreduce turned off before starting my work. and I already checked my MapReduce code in a different cluster that using VM.

Comment: I checked port configurations are correctly replicated. thanks. I have no clue why this is happening T_T

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the `max.xcievers` in `conf/hdfs-site.xml` http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#dfs.datanode.max.xcievers:

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
        <value>4096</value>
</property>
```